# MySQL Connector - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

in my [projest I'm using the MySQL Connector and Entity Framework. I have problem with the following code:

```
   int now = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear;

   var items = (from e in db.Table1
                let date = e.Created.AddDays(90)
                where date.DayOfYear > now
                select e).ToList();
```

but I get the error message:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)'
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 5):

You can not use these type of functions in linq queries you should Subtract 90 days from Now and then do the compare in your query

```
int now = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear.AddDays(-90);
var items = (from e in db.Table1
                where e.Created > now
                select e).ToList();
```